# How display request error in custom django admin error page

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Currently, when 500 errors occur I show the user my custom 500.html error page. The app is used by both administrators and clients, which users are respectively in groups "operator" and "client". The information shown depends on that group.

I would like to apply that concept to the error page. I would like to show the same Traceback error shown when DEBUG = True (not necessary the same style) when logged user is from group "operator".

[image: Information I would like to show to the operator]

I guess there will be an attribute in the request that I can pass through the template and print the errors, but I can't find out which attribute is that. This is the function I use to render the 500.html page:

```
def error_500(request):
    data = {}
    if request.user.groups.filter(name='operator').exists():
        # fill the data dict with the traceback/errors
    return render(request,'app/errors/500.html', data)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Log` functionality is for that. You don't print Tracebacks live it is highly insecure. For more infos check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/error-reporting/

Comment: You should add the ADMINS setting to your settings file. Every time an error happens, django will display your custom 500 error page, and send an email with details of the error to each of the address stated in ADMINS setting. Of course you also must have working email settings. The information is contained in link stated by @hansTheFranz. I think thats what you are looking for.